# How to handle backslash and tilde appearing in a string while using pyparsing

Tags: python, backslash, pyparsing

I need to handle backslash and tilde while using pyparsing in my piece of code and to keep it simple I used printables but this code raises an exception:

```
    import string
    import pyparsing as pp
    from pyparsing import *

    log_display = ("[pts\0]")
    log_display1 = ("[~~  ]")

    ut_user = "[" + Word(printables) + "]"

    log = ut_user

    data = log.parseString(log_display)
    print(data.dump())
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: pyparsing does not do implicit backtracking like regular expressions do, so `Word(printables)` will also consume the trailing ']'.  You'll get some better diagnostics if you use `data.runTests([log_display, log_display1])`. You'll also have to fix the \0 null as reported by user2357112 - just prefix your string with an 'r', as shown in his answer.

Comment: thanks PaulMcG for being so helpful as always!

Answer (score 1):

`"[pts\0]"` does not have a backslash in it. It has a null character. If you wanted a string with a backslash, `r"[pts\0]"` would produce one. When reading input, this will generally not be a problem. String literal escape processing is only applied to string literals, not to user input.

The problem with `"[~~  ]"` has nothing to do with the tilde. The tilde is fine. The problem is the space, which doesn't count as a printable by the standards of `pyparsing.printables`. `pyparsing.printables` is a string containing all ASCII, printable, non-whitespace characters. The proper way to deal with this depends on what characters you actually want to allow.

Comment: Oh Cool thanks. How can I handle the null character? Do I leave out the values after the string or split it? I need only the "pts" if it makes sense.